# Whats the query that filters a table, in order to display only a portion of the results in ms access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a table with many entrys but i only want to display the items with quantity over 0. What a query like that would be like? and how do i use it? Complete noob in Access and VBA

Comment: Why do not you search on internet first? :) thats simpliest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by just what you said, you can try the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE quantity > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a combination of VBA and SQL.  I assume you wish to use vba, as you added the tag.  A good place to start is here:

http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut15.htm

That said if you just want to use the SQL query then Tim's answer has everything you need